# C# atomic property with ONLY get, how to set the value?

Tags: c#, properties

C# allows defining a read-only atomic property with the following syntax

```
// Read-only property
public int MyReadOnlyProp { get; }
```

However, given the backing private property is defined behind the scene I'm not sure how to set the value of this property.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: You can set the value of a readonly property in the constructor.

Comment: Just as a side note, I think you're using "atomic" to mean "automatically implemented" - they are very different concepts. "Atomic" is normally used in terms of memory models, e.g. setting a `decimal` value is not guaranteed to be atomic, so one thread might have written "half" the bits of the new value when another thread reads the variable, resulting in a problem. *Automatically implemented properties* are the ones where you only specify the get or get/set, and the compiler generates the code and the backing field.

Answer (score 4):

Getter only properties can be initialized via an initializer

```
 public int MyReadOnlyProp { get; } = 100;
```

or in the constructor

```
public MyClass()
{
    MyReadOnlyProp = 100;
}
```

but cannot be changed afterwards. As you said: they are read-only.

---

An alternative are auto-implemented properties with a private or protected setter, allowing you to change the value at any time within the class (or struct), but not from outside. This makes them read-only from outside.

```
 public int MyReadOnlyProp { get; private set; }
```

---

And of course there are the good old explicitly implemented properties

```
 private int _myReadOnlyProp;
 public int MyReadOnlyProp { get { return _myReadOnlyProp; } }
```

or with the new expression bodied syntax

```
 private int _myReadOnlyProp;
 public int MyReadOnlyProp => _myReadOnlyProp;
```

You can also use the `readonly` keyword for the backing field that you then must initialize in the constructor or with an initalizer:

```
 private readonly DateTime _today = DateTime.Now;
```

---

Starting with C# 9.0 you can use [Init-only properties](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#init-only-properties). They extend the allowed write phase to object initialization in an object initializer after the constructor has run.

```
public string Name { get; init; }
```

```
var p = new Person { Name = "Joe" };
```

Answer (score -1):

Set it in the constructor, or in the property definition itself:

```
public int MyReadOnlyProp { get; } = 2; // or any integer expression valid at construction time
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks and this way you can set the default. But think of a situation where you want to set this to a custom value in the class initiation, maybe the atomic (only) get is not the solution.